# How filter manytoManyfield before pre choice

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 fields

```
team=models.ForeignKey(Team)
players=models.ManytoManyField(Player)
```

when creating a match, when I select a team  I want to list the players of that team so that I can choose which players will play in the match.
(I want to filter because there are hundreds of maybe thousands of players. I don't want to see the players of other teams.)

```
like this; players=models.ManytoManyfield(players,filter=xxx.team.players)
```

Comment: Are you using Django forms? Seems like you want some kind of validation there, probably on a model level. Can you show more code?

Comment: at the model level yes I'm researching how to do it now I didn't write code. Can it be done with form? can done at the model level?

Comment: Check out [ModelMultipleChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield). You can pass a filtered queryset with the players of the team and it will do the validation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a method it works properly
admin.py

```
class PlayerSelectable(forms.ModelForm):

    winnerplayer = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(verbose_name='deneme',is_stacked=True),required=False,
            queryset = Player.objects.all())



class LolAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'lol_slug': ('name',)}
    form = PlayerSelectable

    class Meta:
        model=LeagueOfLegendsGame
```